# Is there a way to block a method running if it has been a short period of time after it was last run?

Tags: java

I have a method that I only want to run if it hasn't been ran in the last `n` milliseconds.

For example:

```java
public boolean tooLong(int n) {
    int timeSince = timeSinceLastExecution(tooLong);
    //Returns an integer of how long it has been since the last time the tooLong method has been executed
    
    if (timeSince > n)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Is there anything that can replace `timeSinceLastExecutionMethod` that can return a similar result?

Comment: No, there is no such function. You would have to write one. This is commonly called "throttling" or "debouncing", though they're technically slightly different things.

Comment: I know there is not a method like that. However, is there anything that I can write that can replicate that method?

Comment: Make a field of the class that stores the time when the method was last run.  Update that at the end of the method, and check it at the beginning of the method.

Comment: Sure, use `System.nanoTime()` to get a capture of "now", remember that as a field and when you run it again, compare it to that time. If its passed the threshold, let it pass and update the field with the time. Use the `java.time` API (such as `Instant` and `Duration`) for nicer and more readable methods that ultimately achieve the same.

Comment: Does your solution have to return a `boolean`, or  a `yes/no` response, in order to meet your requirements? For example, you could apply the `Observer` design pattern, allow the `tooLong()` callers to register as interested parties, and then notify them when you're good to go. It's cleaner and avoids repeated polling  calls to check availability. From another perspective, could you hold (block) calls on `tooLong()`, and respond when ready? A bit more detail about your specific scenario and constraints will make it easier to help you find a good solution that meets your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in function for this, both because it’s uncommon, and because it’s easy to implement oneself:

```
private static final long MIN_COOLDOWN = Duration.ofMinutes(5).toMillis();

private long lastCallTime;

public boolean tooLong(int n) {
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (now - lastCallTime < MIN_COOLDOWN) {
        return false;
    }

    lastCallTime = now;

    // Actual method logic goes here.

    return true;
}
```